# A statement equivalent to $\exists ! x P(x)$

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I'm trying to write a statement in logic symbols that says there is a unique $x$ such that $P(x)$ is true. I've heard of writing this down as $\exists !x P(x) $. But I think I'm not allowed to use the symbol $\exists !$. Now I'm trying to write an equivalent statement without using that symbol. I've come up with two statements, but I'm not sure if one of them is correct:

1. $\exists x ,\lnot \exists y (P(x) \land P(y) \land \lnot (x=y))$
2. $\exists x P(x) \land \lnot \exists y (P(y) \land \lnot (x=y))$

My doubt with the first one is that I've never seen a construction like $\exists x, \lnot \exists y (...)$.

My doubt with the second one is that I'm not sure if the variable $x$ in this part $\lnot \exists y (P(y) \land \lnot (x=y))$ is interpreted as a free variable or as the variable with the property $\exists x P(x) $.

Comment: Remember that $\lnot\exists y(\dots)$ is the same as $\forall y\lnot(\dots)$

Comment: possible duplicate of [Write ‘There is exactly 1 person…’ without the uniqueness quantifier](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394609/write-there-is-exactly-1-person-without-the-uniqueness-quantifier)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that $\lnot\exists y(\dots)$ is the same as $\forall y\lnot(\dots)$, your first one is equivalent to:

$$\exists x\forall y \left(\lnot P(x)\lor \lnot P(y)\lor(x=y)\right)$$

So, as another poster said, all you'd need is $\exists x:\lnot P(x)$ to prove this statement. So this statement is actually saying something more complicated.

The second statement is correct, although I'd mind the parentheses there:

$$\exists x \left(P(x) \land \lnot \exists y \left(P(y) \land \lnot (x=y)\right)\right)$$

and again you can replace $\lnot\exists y$ with $\forall y\lnot$, which other answers above have done.

But I prefer to think of $\exists!$ as being shorthand for "there is one, and at most one." That is, two completely separate statements joined by $\land$. So I'd write it as:

$$\left(\exists xP(x)\right)\land\forall y\forall z \left(\left(P(y)\land P(z)\right)\implies y=z\right)$$

Comment: In your last statement, could I replace: $\forall y : \forall z$ with $\forall (y,z)$ ? Alex Kocurek tells me the parenthesis are incorrect in my second statement. Is this correct ?

Comment: Yeah, $\forall y,z$ is technically shorthand for $\forall y\forall z$, @Kasper

Answer (score 6):

Your second statement is almost correct, but you need some parentheses. You want to say "There is an $x$ such that $P(x)$ and no other $y$ different from $x$ is such that $P(y)$." This is formalized as: $$\exists x [P(x) \wedge \forall y (x \neq y \rightarrow \neg P(y))]$$

where $x \neq y$ abbreviates $\neg (x = y)$. Alternatively, you can write: $$\exists x [P(x) \wedge \neg\exists y (x \neq y \wedge P(y))]$$

which is like your answer, with appropriate parentheses.

Answer (score 6):

In your second expression, you have all the right *pieces* (propositions) covered, but you need to check which parentheses you need to "put the pieces together".

Note that in what you wrote:

$$\color{blue}{\bf \exists x P(x)} \land \color{red}{\bf \lnot \exists y (P(y) \land \lnot ({\color{black}{\bf  x}}=y))}$$

...we have the conjunction of two statements (joined by $\land$). The appearance of $x$ in the right hand expression is unrelated to its appearance in the left hand (blue) proposition. That is, $x$ is *unbound* on the right. We want to say that its appearance on the right is the **same** $x$ we are bounding on the left, so we need a large bracket to enclose **everything** that follows $\exists x$. That gives us:

$$\color{blue}{\bf \exists x \Big[P(x) \land \lnot \exists y (P(y) \land \lnot (x=y))\Big]}\tag{$\dagger$}$$

And with the added bracket, all is good: $\dagger$ is now equivalent to $\exists\, !\, x \,P(x)$.

Comment: That is what I wanted to know ! Thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome, Kasper!

Comment: @amWhy: The color coding gets them everytime! :-) +1

Answer (score 3):

The first one is not correct. Consider the case where $\forall x, \neg P(x)$; then it is true that there exists $x$ such that no $y$ satisfies at the same time $P(x)$ and other conditions.

The second one is correct (assuming the right parentheses). Maybe if you rewrite it as $\exists x (P(x) \wedge \forall y (P(y) \Rightarrow x=y))$ it will be clearer.

Comment: Would the second one be incorrect if I write it like this:

$\exists x (P(x)) \land \lnot \exists y (P(y) \land \lnot (x=y))$

I think this is incorrect, but I'm not sure why. Is this because it's not clear what is meant with the $x$ in the second part ?