# Using Quantifiers to express "At least two"

Tags: discrete-mathematics, quantifiers

I have been stumped trying to solve problem **e**. I am confused as how to state "At least two students..." using quantifiers! 
I know if it were ONE student it would be: ∃x,y(Q(x,Jeopardy)).
And all students would be:∀x,y(Q(x,Jeopardy))
 So how can I expand on this? 
 [image]

Comment: We can say at least two satisfy $\varphi$ by writing $\exists u\exists v(\lnot(u=v)\land \varphi(u)\land\varphi(v))$.

Comment: It stands for any formula you may need. I left it to you to choose the relevant $\varphi$ in your particular problem.

Comment: I deleted my comment right as you posted this, I reread it a few times and figured it out! Thank you for the concise answer.

Comment: You are welcome. The same kind of trick can be used to make a sentence that says there exist at least $3$, at least $4$, and so on. It cannot be used to make a single sentence that says there are infinitely many.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $P(x)$ denotes the predicate that $x$ has been on *Jeopardy*.

One can assert $\exists x,y$ s.t. $P(x) \land P(y) \land x\neq y$.

Comment: Do I not have to use the given statement Q(x,y)?

Comment: @EvanBechtol $P(x)$ is $Q(x,\mathrm{Jeopardy})$.

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you very much. This answers my question :)

Answer (score 1):

As another way to put this, this is the negation of the "there exists at most one" quantifier, which I usually denote as $\;\langle !x :: P(x) \rangle\;$.  Looking at [another answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/398539/11994) and doing some basic manipulations, that negation would be
$$
    \langle \forall z :: \langle \exists x :: x \not= z \land P(x) \rangle \rangle
$$
where of course $\;P(x)\;$ stands for "$\;x\;$ has been on *Jeopardy*", and $\;x,z\;$ range over the school students.

Perhaps that looks counterintuitive, but it is correct: you could read it as, "Whichever $\;z\;$ you take away (even if $\;P\;$ holds for it), you will still have at least one $\;x\;$ left that satisfies $\;P\;$."

Note how this is the only formula which contains $\;P\;$ only once: the usual formulations have two occurrences of $\;P\;$.