# Is there logical quantifier for unique element

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I know $\exists$ means at least one element and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205464/quantifier-for-there-is-at-most-one) is answer for at most one. I have read that $!\exists$ means exactly one element, but can anyone confirm that?

Comment: Usually $\exists!$

Answer (score 0):

To denote that there exists a unique $x$ such that a statement $P(x)$ is true, we usually write:

$$\exists!x: P(x)$$