# Verifying logical equivalence in first order logic

Tags: first-order-logic

***I am given this definition:***

> Let the domain of discourse $D$ be the set of all people and houses,
>   the unary relation symbol $P$ is the set of people, and the unary
>   relation $H$ is the set of houses, and and the binary relation $A$ is
>   always interpreted as the set of pairs $(p,h)$ such that $p$ is a
>   person,$h$ is a house and person $p$ has access to house $h$.

**Question:**

> *Express the following using an appropriate sentence of first order logic:*
>
> > No house can be accessed by more than one person.

***Attempt:***

I attempted expressing the sentence and came up with this:

$\forall x(H(X) \Rightarrow \forall y\forall z ((P(y) \land P(x) \land A(y,x) \land A(z,x))\Rightarrow z=y))$

While the answer given is this:

$\forall x \forall y ((P(X) \land P(y) \land x \neq y)\Rightarrow \neg \exists z(H(z) \land A(x,z) \land A(y,z)))$

Is there any way of deducing whether or not the two sentences are describing the same thing?

Comment: Just for fun, the following simpler statement is also equivalent: $$
\langle \forall h :: H(h) \;\Rightarrow\; \langle \exists q :: \langle \forall p :: P(p) \land A(p,h) \Rightarrow p = q \rangle \rangle \rangle
$$  Hint: use the equivalent form of the 'at most one quantifier' $\;\langle ! x :: \ldots \rangle\;$ given in http://math.stackexchange.com/a/398539/11994.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to "compare" the two formulae, we have to re-write yours as follows :

> $∀z[H(z) \to ∀x∀y((P(y)∧P(x)∧A(x,z)∧A(y,z)) \to x=y)]$

that is equivalent to :

> $∀z∀x∀y[H(z) \to (P(y)∧P(x)∧A(x,z)∧A(y,z)) \to x=y)]$

becuase $x,y$ are not free in $H(z)$.

The answer is :

> $∀x∀y[(P(x)∧P(y)∧x≠y) \to ∀z¬(H(z)∧A(x,z)∧A(y,z))]$

i.e.

> $∀x∀y∀z[(P(x)∧P(y)∧x≠y) \to ¬(H(z)∧A(x,z)∧A(y,z))]$.

We have now to "compare" the two "propositional" parts.

Yours is :

> $\lnot H(z) \lor \lnot (P(y)∧P(x)∧A(x,z)∧A(y,z)) \lor x=y$

i.e.

> > $\lnot H(z) \lor \lnot P(y) \lor \lnot P(x) \lor \lnot A(x,z) \lor \lnot A(y,z) \lor x=y$.

The answer is :

> $\lnot (P(x)∧P(y)∧x≠y) \lor ¬(H(z)∧A(x,z)∧A(y,z))$

i.e.

> > $\lnot P(x) \lor \lnot P(y) \lor x=y \lor \lnot H(z) \lor \lnot A(x,z) \lor \lnot A(y,z)$.

---

In conclusion : YES, they are the same.